# Homeomorphism between space of characters and compact set

Tags: functional-analysis

I am not sure how to construct homeomorphism between $\Omega(C^1([0,1]))$and $[0,1]$, where $\Omega(C^1([0,1]))$ denotes set of characters over algebra $C^1([0,1]).$
I know that homeomorphism between $\Omega(C([0,1]))$ and $[0,1]$ exist (for every $x\in[0,1]$ you can define $ev_x(f)=f(x)$), but I am not sure how to the other one.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What group structure are you placing on $[0,1]$?

Comment: I don't understand what your exact question is. You've already said what the correct homeomorphism is. Are you asking why $\mathrm{ev}_x \leftrightarrow x$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: I just wasn't sure if I can use that homeomorphism, because $C^1([0,1])$ is subalgebra of $C([0,1])$.

Comment: One can show that all maxiaml ideals are of the form $I_t:=\{f\in C^1([0,1]): f(t)=0\}$ for some $t\in [0,1]$. The proof is almost the same as well know proof for algebras of continuous functions. Now take any character $\chi$. Its kernel is a maximal ideal, i.e. of the form $I_t$ for some $t$. Now it is clear that $\chi=\operatorname{ev}_t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can show that all maxiaml ideals are of the form $I_t:=\{f\in C^1([0,1]):f(t)=0\}$ for some $t\in[0,1]$. The proof is almost the same as well know proof for algebras of continuous functions. Now take any character $\chi$. Its kernel is a maximal ideal, i.e. of the form It for some $t\in[0,1]$. Now it is clear that $\chi=\operatorname{ev}_t$.